# Play Video on PiTFT instead of through the HDMI

Tags: pi-2, video, pitft, omxplayer

I bought the PiTFT Adafruit display for the Pi. (Adafruit 2.8" TFT display (PID 2423) for Raspberry Pi). My Pi is the Raspberry Pi 2B.

I downloaded the recommended Adafruit, (Jessie) image to the microSD and everything works well from the OS standpoint. The display shows the UI of the operating system. All is good so far, but when I would like to run a video on the LCD, it always shows up on a screen connected to the HDMI output on the Pi.

I am using the omxplayer. If I try `omxplayer /home/pi/movies/my-test.mp4`, the HDMI output is used.

If I try the parameter `--display=4`, nothing happens. I found in the Raspian documentation that 4 should be the LCD, but this seems not to work. The video is not playing. Neither on the HDMI display nor on the LCD. The PiTFT still shows the graphical OS UI.

Hope any good ideas out there.
Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a tool like [fbcp](https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) or [raspi2fb](https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2fb) which copies one framebuffer to another.

The `--display`  option is only relevant for the official display.

Comment: Hi @flakeshake. Many thanks. I have tried `fbcp` now and it works perfeclty. Cheers John